# VSTS - Is there a way to only run a task if a specific task has failed?

Tags: azure-devops

I need to run a publish task in my build definition but only if a certain task before it has failed. If the other task passes I want this to be ignored and not run.

Is there a way of doing this?

I was hoping that I could set an output variable based on the task success and then use that variable in a custom condition to run the task if it's failed.

I can't see how to set an output variable if the task fails. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- In the Task settings expand the "Control Options"
- Choose in "Run this task" - `Only when a previous task has failed`.

[image]

**If you want to run the task only if last/specific task failed:**

Suppose your specific task (the one you examine in regards to its status) is called `A`. The goal is to call another build task (let's say `B`) only in case `A` fails.

- Define a [custom build variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch#user-defined-variables), call it `task.A.status` and set to `success`
- Create another build task, e.g. `C` and schedule it right after `A`; condition it to only run if `A` fails - there's a standard condition for that
- The task `C` should only do one thing - set `task.A.status` build variable to 'failure' (like this, if we are talking PowerShell: `Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=task.A.status]failure"`)
- Finally, the task `B` is scheduled sometime after `C` and [is conditioned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/process/conditions?view=vsts#enable-a-custom-condition) to run in case `task.A.status` equals `failure`, like this: `eq(variables['task.A.status'], 'failure')`

[image]

Comment: That runs it if any previous task fails. This new task can only run if a specific task fails before it.

Comment: Perfect - that should do it. I think i'll have to use the option of task C as the task i'm running is not a powershell task. Easily sorted though with a task straight after the one that could potentially fail.

Comment: Hey, what is that condition to run task `C` if `A` fails? What is that specific condition you are talking about? I see the option to check `Only when a previous task has failed`. So it can be any task above `C` which is failed not just `A`.

Comment: @MehulParmar you need to choose “custom conditions”

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk What exactly to write to check if just the previous task has failed? Can you help?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk There doesn't seem to be any standard functionality for checking the *previous* task has failed even using a "custom condition". Not sure this answer is valid.

Answer (score 4):

You can check previous tasks through PowerShell with build REST API, for example to check taskA (display name) and run taskB if taskA failed:

1. Check `Allow scripts to access the OAuth token` option in the Phase
2. Add PowerShell task (Run this task: `Only when a previous task has failed`; Arguments: `-targetTaskName "taskA" -collectionURL $(Build.Repository.Uri) -projectName $(System.TeamProject) -buildId $(Build.BuildId) -token $(System.AccessToken)`)

Code:

```
param(
    [string]$token,
        [string]$targetTaskName,
        [string]$collectionURL,
        [string]$projectName,
        [string]$buildId
    )
    $buildTimelineREST="$collectionURL$projectName/_apis/build/builds/$buildId/Timeline?api-version=4.1"
    $base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "test",$token)))
    $result= Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $buildTimelineREST -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
    $targetTask=$result.records | where { $_.Name -eq $targetTaskName }
    Write-Host $targetTask.result
    if($targetTask.result -eq "failed"){
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=isTaskAFailed;]true"
    }
```

3. The taskB (Run this task: `Custom conditions`; Custom condition: `eq(variables['isTaskAFailed'],'true'`)

Comment: Hello, is the method still working? I am getting an error while sending the request.

Answer (score 1):

Further to starian chen-MSFT's code, which will work for build pipelines, below is what I pulled together for release pipelines (in case it is useful for anyone). This will output a pipeline variable "deploymentStatus" that equals the status of the task (as defined by Azure DevOps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get%20release?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#taskstatus):

```
$targetTaskName = "Some Task Name"
$token = $env:System_AccessToken
$releaseURL = $env:System_TeamFoundationServerUri
$projectName = $env:System_TeamProject
$releaseId= $env:Release_ReleaseId
$environmentId = $env:Release_EnvironmentId
$releaseAttemptNumber = $env:Release_AttemptNumber

$releaseREST="$releaseURL$projectName/_apis/release/releases/$releaseId/environments/$environmentId/?api-version=5.1-preview.6"
Write-Host "GET request to Azure Pipelines with URL: $releaseREST"
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "test",$token)))
$result= Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $releaseREST -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

$targetReleaseAttempt = $result.deploySteps | where { $_.attempt -eq $releaseAttemptNumber}
$targetTask = $targetReleaseAttempt.releaseDeployPhases.deploymentJobs.tasks | where { $_.name -eq $targetTaskName }
$targetTask

$targetTaskStatus = $targetTask.status
Write-Host "Setting variable deploymentStatus to $targetTaskStatus"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=deploymentStatus;]$targetTaskStatus"
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [@Merivale](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6522463/merivale)'s answer this was the code that worked for me;

```
$targetTaskName = "SomeTaskName"

$pat = ":$(System.AccessToken)"
$b  = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pat)
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($b)

$releaseURL="$(System.TeamFoundationServerUri)"
$releaseId= $(Release.ReleaseId)
$environmentId = $(Release.EnvironmentId)
$releaseAttemptNumber = $(Release.AttemptNumber)

$releaseREST_p1="$releaseURL"
$releaseREST=$releaseREST_p1+"$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/release/releases/$releaseId/environments/$environmentId/?api-version=5.1-preview.6"
Write-Host "GET request to Azure Pipelines with URL: $releaseREST"

$result= Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $releaseREST -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{'Authorization' = "Basic $token"}

$targetReleaseAttempt = $result.deploySteps | where { $_.attempt -eq $releaseAttemptNumber}
$targetTask = $targetReleaseAttempt.releaseDeployPhases.deploymentJobs.tasks | where { $_.name -eq $targetTaskName }
$targetTask

$targetTaskStatus = $targetTask.status
Write-Host "Setting variable releaseStatus to $targetTaskStatus"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=releaseStatus;]$targetTaskStatus"
```