# In Azure DevOps can Tasks within the same Job depend on each other?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

My release pipeline in Azure DevOps has a Job. This Job has 3 tasks: A, B, C.
I need to set this up so that B and C only run when A succeeds, but if A succeeds and B fails, then C still runs.

I can't seem to be able to figure out the correct set of conditions to achieve that. According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops) you can make Tasks depend on status of another Job, but doesn't look like it's possible for a Task to depend on another Task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default each task will be executed only if the previous task succeeded, so task B will be executed only if A succeeded.

You want that task C will be executed even if task B fails, so add this condition to task B:

```
continueOnError: true
```

Now task C will be executed if task B failed, but if task A failed, tasks B & C will be skipped.

For example, 3 PowerShell tasks:

```
- powershell: 'Write-Host "A"'
  displayName: A

- powershell: 'Write-Host "B"'
  displayName: B
  continueOnError: true

- powershell: 'Write-Host "C"'
  displayName: C
```

In the above behavior the build will be in Orange color (partial succeeded) and if you will have other tasks after C they are also will be executed, if you want that task B will red and only task C will be be run after it, it's not so easy to do it, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52312222) question & answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can achive this with the control options of each task:

[image]

**Task A:**

```
[ ] continue on error
```

---

**Task B:**

```
[x] continue on error
```

---

**Task C:**

```
[ ] continue on error
```

---

Hope this helps

Comment: If in task C he will mark "Even id error..." so task C will be executed even task A will failed and is not good.

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk edited, I think it should works like that, just leave this option and `C` will continue, even if `B` fails.

Comment: Yes, just like my answer :)