# Azure - custom condition in YAML based pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I've an yaml based azure CI/CT pipeline. I've a task defined as below:

```
- task: PublishTestResults@2
  displayName: 'Publish PCOM Test Results'
  condition: always()
  inputs:
    testResultsFormat: NUnit
    testResultsFiles: '*.xml'
    searchFolder: '$(Common.TestResultsDirectory)/$(Build.SourceBranchName)/$(Build.BuildNumber)/test-results/PCOM'
    mergeTestResults: true
    testRunTitle: 'PCOM Tests'
```

It looks for all '*.xml' files under a particular s3 location. But the `xml` files will be created only if the below task is successful:

```
- bash: 'perl run_aws_cli.pl $(Build.BuildNumber) $(Build.SourceBranchName) $(s3Bucket) $(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
  workingDirectory: 'azure-pipeline/scripts'
  displayName: 'Run ECS Tasks'
```

So I want a custom condition to check if the later task is successful then only search `xml` files in the directory else don't search for it.
Currently it's searching always and the earlier task(**Publish PCOM Test Results**) is failing.

Comment: How can I create a variable inside a script and use that variable across different task in same stage?

Comment: Hi Biswajit Maharana, did you get a chance to implement the solution that 4c74356b41 suggested? Were you able to resolve?

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT yes I found the solution

Comment: Good to know, if 4c74356b41's  reply helped or gave a right direction. Appreciate for marking it as an answer. Otherwise, feel free to share your own solution here, which will also help others in the community.

Answer (score 0):

just do `condition: succeeded()` on your second task. this will only run if all the tasks before that run successfully. if you want a more sophisticated option, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52312222/vsts-is-there-a-way-to-only-run-a-task-if-a-specific-task-has-failed) thread.

Alternatively, you can probably get more information on the build status from the API.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Comment: In my case my first task will always execute successfully and in few scenarios it will create the xml files(not always), so in that case how can I add a condition in my second task?

Comment: in that case you need to create a script step that will check if it did create those files and assign a variable you can use in the custom condition to determine if the step is needed. but its probably just easier to put a check inside of your script to not do anything if there are no files

Comment: I can create a script to check for those files and set some variables inside that script step which can be a Boolean deciding whether to run the next step or not. How can I create a variable inside a script and use that variable across different task in same stage?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts

Comment: There is no info regarding how to modify the variables define in the yaml inside a script and use the modified value in the subsequent task

Comment: read the link, its all there with examples how to set and how to use literally.

Comment: There is a section saying variables are always read-only in pipeline, but in my case I want to modify the pipeline variable inside a script, I didn't find this anywhere in the link. Sorry

Comment: the link is literally to the section about modifying variables in the script. only the system variables are read only, and you are not looking to modify those. just open the link and wait it to load. I have no idea how you cannot just skim thought that article to find the information you need