# Conditionally run an Azure DevOps job only if a specific prior job has failed

Tags: azure-devops, conditional-statements, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

In Azure DevOps, I'm trying to make it so that a release job (not a YAML pipeline job) only runs if a specific prior job has failed. One of the pre-defined conditions for running a job is "Only when a previous job has failed", but this is not appropriate because it includes all prior jobs, rather than just the last job (or better yet, a job of the users choosing).

Please note that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52312222/vsts-is-there-a-way-to-only-run-a-task-if-a-specific-task-has-failed) focuses on tasks within a job and is not the answer that I am looking for.

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for conditions under "How can I trigger a job if a previous job succeeded with issues?", I can access the result of a previous job -

```
eq(dependencies.A.result,'SucceededWithIssues')
```

Looking at the logs for a previous release, the `AGENT_JOBNAME` for the job that I wish to check is `Post Deployment Tests`, so that would mean that my condition should look like this. However, Azure DevOps wont even let me save my release -

```
not(eq(dependencies.Post Deployment Tests.result, 'succeeded'))
```

> Job condition for job "Swap Slots Back on Post Deployment Test Failure" in stage "Dev" is invalid: Unexpected symbol: 'Deployment'.

I've tried to wrap the job name in quotes, but I get similar errors -

```
not(eq(dependencies.'Post Deployment Tests'.result, 'succeeded'))
not(eq(dependencies."Post Deployment Tests".result, 'succeeded'))
```

I've also tried to reference my job using underscores, which does allow me to save the release but then results in an error at run time -

```
not(eq(dependencies.Post_Deployment_Tests.result, 'succeeded'))
```

> Unrecognized value: 'dependencies'.

How can I achieve me goal of conditionally running a job only if a specific prior job has failed?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I achieve me goal of conditionally running a job only if a
>   specific prior job has failed?

1.You should know that Yaml pipeline and Classic pipeline use **difference** technologies.

See [feature ability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/pipelines-get-started?view=azure-devops#feature-availability), they have **different** features. Also, they have **quite different** behavior for Conditions though they(`Yaml,Classic Build,Classic Release`) all support job conditions.

The `eq(dependencies.'Post Deployment Tests'.result, 'succeeded')` you're trying is not supported in Classic(UI) Release pipeline. It's for Yaml:

[image]

It's expected behavior to get error like `Unrecognized value: 'dependencies'` cause the job dependency is not supported in Release pipeline. See this [old ticket](https://developercommunityapi.westus.cloudapp.azure.com/idea/720680/cannot-configure-job-dependencies-in-release-pipel.html).

Comment: Sad times. Another example of the poor user experience provided by Azure DevOps that I'm going to have to try and work around. Do you know if this is at least on the roadmap?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, but I didn't find similar request in our user voice forum. I suggest you can submit [a feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html) in our DC forum to share your idea. The team would consider it seriously if it gets enough votes. You can share the link here and we who interested in that could vote for you too :)

Comment: Was needing the same feature to workaround another feature that is not completely implemented in devops...
Would be great if one day MSFT stops reinventing the wheel for a 2nd version using another technology (here YAML), before they have finished the 1st one...

Comment: Hi @LiohAu Did you raised a feature request? I think we still don't have option to direct define dependencies and read variables using dependencies in Classic azure. Or you found any workaround? I know has been long but problem still exists :)