# Azure DevOps, When a job in the stage is successful, how can it be ensured that stage is successful or partially successful?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When one of the jobs in the stage is successful and the other is fail, how can it be ensured that that stage is successful and proceeds to the next stage?

If I'm more descriptive,

```
Pipeline
    A(Stage)                      -->                B(Stage) 
      -Job1(failed)                                    -Job1
                                                       - ...
      -Job2(succeeded)
         (run only when previous job failed)
```

When Job 1 in A stage is fail, automatically Job 2 running. But in this way, stage A is resulted 'Failed'. Therefore, Stage B is never running because of previous stage failed.

"Trigger even when the selected stages partially succeed" button is not working for stage B because previous stage marked as "fail".

Additionally, I tried:

If i mark all tasks  inside "A -> Job1" as "Continue on error" and i checked "Trigger even when the selected stages partially succeed" box in stage B  this time "Job 2"  not running because "run only when previous job failed " option marked on job 2. There is no option like "run only when previous job  partially succeeded".

In addition, custom condition not working in Job 2, its show null for "Agent.JobStatus" variable. If these "SucceededWithIssues" and "Failed" status available for "Agent.JobStatus" it can be run but I couldn't come to a conclusion here because null value of JobStatus.

Comment: I think a better approach would be to accept that stage A has failed, but make stage B run anyway, by giving it a condition such as `always()`. Have you tried anything like that?

Comment: Hi @VinceBowdren, in this case stage B always run but i don't want this. If Job 1 **or** Job 2 in stage A successful then Stage B must run. (If both of them fail, stage B is should not run)

Comment: I don't think there's any direct support for that in azure pipelines conditions. You may have to code a workaround using either the REST API to specifically check those two tasks' statuses, or add variable-setting tasks to be able to record and reference those tasks' statuses. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/52312222/174843 for some suggestions.

Comment: I plan to do this as a last resort, but I'm looking for a different generic solution for a cleaner build. Thanks for your opinions.